# Ruby on Rails, testing for nil in second dimension of the params array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm having a bear with some very basic code, which is ...

```
.form
  = semantic_form_for 'thought', :url => thoughtstep2_path do  |f|
    = f.inputs :name => 'Add Something' do
      = f.input :title, :hint => "A Hint", :input_html => { :value => params[:thought][:title] }
      = f.input :moreinfo, :as => "text", :hint => "Another Hint", :input_html => {:value => params[:thought][:moreinfo]}
    = f.buttons
```

Because the params array I am using to set the :value has a second dimension it bugs out with

> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!

I've tried all sorts of get arounds but to no avail, any ideas anyone?

Comment: And with using a view helper if [:thought][:title] is set ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment not sure what you mean though?  Could you expand?

Answer (score 1):

A few options to try:

```
{ :value => params[:thought].try(:[], :title) }
{ :value => (params[:thought][:title] rescue nil) }
{ :value => params[:thought] && params[:thought][:title] }
{ :value => (params[:thought][:title] if params[:thought]) }
```

I'd suggest that you pick the one that you personally find the most readable.

Comment: Thanks for that, nice set of options.  I've tried all the combinations and in each case I get a compile error for a line such as = f.input :title, :hint => "A hint", :input_html => { :value => params[:thought][:title] if params[:thought] }

Comment: The compile error is compile error
/git/app/views/thoughts/new.html.haml:10: syntax error, unexpected kIF_MOD, expecting '}'
...=> params[:thought][:title] if params[:thought] }

Comment: @creativetechnologist...it should be `:input_html => {:value => (params[:thought][:title] if params[:thought]) }` instead of `{ :value => params[:thought][:title] if params[:thought] }`..there should be a `()`

Comment: I've editing the comment to add the necessary parens.  Good catch @rubyprince.

Answer (score -1):

In your helper :

```
def test(value)
    if value
        return value;
    else
        return '';
    end
end
```

In your view :

```
.form
    = semantic_form_for 'thought', :url => thoughtstep2_path do  |f|
        = f.inputs :name => 'Add Something' do
        = f.input :title, :hint => "A Hint", :input_html => { :value => test(params[:thought][:title]) }
        = f.input :moreinfo, :as => "text", :hint => "Another Hint", :input_html => {:value => params[:thought][:moreinfo]}
= f.buttons
```

I'm not sure about this but it's may be a way to fix your problem

Comment: Yes I tried that earlier but I think that it broke because the first dimension of the array is also nil.